# How can I encode some character alphabet into another character alphabet?

Tags: python

I want encode some 256 letter alphabet into 90 letter alphabet how can I do it in Python. Is there any standard library or extended module in pure python.

```
import os

string256 = os.urandom(32)
alphabet = []
alphabet.append(chr(0x21))
alphabet.extend([chr(x) for x in range(0x23, 0x2b+1)])
alphabet.extend([chr(x) for x in range(0x2d, 0x3a+1)])
alphabet.extend([chr(x) for x in range(0x3c, 0x5b+1)])
alphabet.extend([chr(x) for x in range(0x5d, 0x7e+1)])

# alphabet has 90 letters
s = encode(string256, alphabet)

d = decode(string256, alphabet)
assert(d == string256)
```

How to do such encoding in Python?

Comment: translate() works on 256 to 256 not 256 to 90 and reverse - it is not what is need.

Comment: OK, I didn't read your question carefully enough. So you want to keep all the information encoded in 8 bit characters, but use only 90 different characters to store the info (which means a single byte needs to be translated into more than one character)? Does it have to be 90 characters? Or would 64 characters be OK, too ([`base64`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html))?